# Convert type from struct table to base.FixedDataGrid in GO

Tags: mongodb, go, struct

i'm having a trouble converting my struct table to fixedDataGrid, because i need my data to be a fixedDataGrid so that i can use machine learning methods from GoLearn lib.

My struct is like this:

```
type dataStruct struct{
    Sepal_length string
    Sepal_width string
    Petal_length string
    Petal_width string
    Species string
}
```

So when i get my data from my mongo db, i get them like this:

```
var results []dataStruct
err := col.Find(nil).All(&results)
```

Is there a way to convert my "results" from []dataStruct type to base.FixedDataGrid ??

CreateModel function:

```
func CreateModel(c echo.Context) error {
    fmt.Println("====> Entry CreateModel function");
    //var results []dataStruct
    var Success bool = false

    Db := db.MgoDb{}
    Db.Init()
    defer Db.Close()

    col := Db.C(db.TrainingDataCollection)
    var results dataStruct
    if err := col.Find(nil).All(results); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR WHILE GETTING THE TRAINING DATA")
    } else {
       //fmt.Println("Results All: ", results) 
       Success = true
    }

fmt.Println("=============",results)

//Initialises a new KNN classifier
cls := knn.NewKnnClassifier("euclidean", "linear", 2)

//Do a training-test split
trainData, testData := base.InstancesTrainTestSplit(results, 0.55)
cls.Fit(trainData)

//Calculates the Euclidean distance and returns the most popular label
predictions, err := cls.Predict(testData)

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(predictions)

// Prints precision/recall metrics
confusionMat, err := evaluation.GetConfusionMatrix(testData, predictions)

if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Sprintf("Unable to get confusion matrix: %s", err.Error()))
}

fmt.Println(evaluation.GetSummary(confusionMat))

return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, Success)

}
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i solved the issue: Actually there is a function `InstancesFromMat64(row int, col int, matrix)` than creates `instances` from a `float64` matrix, and this is what i used:

```
func CreateModel(c echo.Context) error {
    fmt.Println("====> Entry CreateModel function");
    var Success bool = false

    Db := db.MgoDb{}
    Db.Init()
    defer Db.Close()

    col := Db.C(db.TrainingDataCollection)
    var results dataStruct
    if err := col.Find(nil).All(&results); err != nil {
           fmt.Println("ERROR WHILE GETTING THE TRAINING DATA")
    } else {
           Success = true
     }

   Data := make([]float64, len(results*nbAttrs)

   /**** Filling the Data var with my dataset data *****/

   mat := mat64.NewDense(row,nbAttrs,Data)
   inst := base.InstancesFromMat64(row,nbAttrs,mat)

   //Selecting the class attribute for our instance
   attrs := inst.AllAttributes()
   inst.AddClassAttribute(attrs[4])

   //Initialise a new KNN classifier
   cls := knn.NewKnnClassifier("manhattan","linear",3)

   //Training-tessting split
   trainData, testData := base.InstancesTrainTestSplit(inst,0.7)

   /*******          Continue the Model creation                ******/
```

I'll be glad if my answer helps someone.

Thanks a lot @mkopriva for your help !

Answer (score 0):

[base.FixedDataGrid](https://godoc.org/github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/base#FixedDataGrid) is an `interface`, so what you need to do is to implement that interface, that is, implement all of its methods, on the type you want to use as `FixedDataGrid`.

Since you want to use `[]dataStruct`, a slice of `dataStruct`s, which is an *unnamed type*, as `FixedDataGrid` you will have to declare a new type to be able to add methods to it because you can add methods only to *named types*. For example something like this:

```
type dataStructList []dataStruct
```

Now, if you take a look at the documentation, you can see that the `FixedDataGrid` interface declares two methods `RowString` and `Size` but also *embeds* another interface, the [base.DataGrid](https://godoc.org/github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/base#DataGrid) interface, which means you need to implement the methods declared by `DataGrid` as well. So, given your new `dataStructList` type, you can do something like this:

```
func (l dataStructList) RowString(int) string { /* ... */ }
func (l dataStructList) Size() (int, int) { /* ... */ }
func (l dataStructList) GetAttribute(base.Attribute) (base.AttributeSpec, error)  { /* ... */ }
func (l dataStructList) AllAttributes() []base.Attribute  { /* ... */ }
func (l dataStructList) AddClassAttribute(base.Attribute) error  { /* ... */ }
func (l dataStructList) RemoveClassAttribute(base.Attribute) error  { /* ... */ }
func (l dataStructList) AllClassAttributes() []base.Attribute  { /* ... */ }
func (l dataStructList) Get(base.AttributeSpec, int) []byte  { /* ... */ }
func (l dataStructList) MapOverRows([]base.AttributeSpec, func([][]byte, int) (bool, error)) error  { /* ... */ }
```

After you've implemented the `/* ... */` parts you can then start using `dataStructList` as a `FixedDataGrid`, so something like this:

```
var results []dataStruct
err := col.Find(nil).All(&results)
fdg := dataStructList(results) // you can use fdg as FixedDataGrid
```

Or

```
var results dataStructList // you can use results as FixedDataGrid
err := col.Find(nil).All(&results)
```

**Update**:

After you've implemented all of those methods on the `dataStructList` all you need is the type of the `results` variable inside your function:

```
func CreateModel(c echo.Context) error {
    fmt.Println("====> Entry CreateModel function")
    //var results []dataStruct
    var Success bool = false

    Db := db.MgoDb{}
    Db.Init()
    defer Db.Close()

    col := Db.C(db.TrainingDataCollection)
    var results dataStructList // <--- use the type that implements the interface
    if err := col.Find(nil).All(&results); err != nil { // <-- pass a pointer to results
        fmt.Println("ERROR WHILE GETTING THE TRAINING DATA")
    } else {
        //fmt.Println("Results All: ", results)
        Success = true
    }

    fmt.Println("=============", results)

    //Initialises a new KNN classifier
    cls := knn.NewKnnClassifier("euclidean", "linear", 2)

    //Do a training-test split
    trainData, testData := base.InstancesTrainTestSplit(results, 0.55) // <-- this will work because results if of type dataStructList, which implements the base.FixedDataGrid interface.
    cls.Fit(trainData)

    //Calculates the Euclidean distance and returns the most popular label
    predictions, err := cls.Predict(testData)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(predictions)

    // Prints precision/recall metrics
    confusionMat, err := evaluation.GetConfusionMatrix(testData, predictions)

    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Unable to get confusion matrix: %s", err.Error()))
    }

    fmt.Println(evaluation.GetSummary(confusionMat))

    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, Success)

}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

So you mean i have to write all the methods declared in FixedDataGrid & DataGrid ?

and to implement the interface i just have to do like this in my function :


`func CreateModel(i base.FixedDataGrid) error {/***   ****/ }`

Comment: Yes, if, for examle, you want to call this [InferID3Tree function](https://godoc.org/github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/trees#InferID3Tree) and you want to pass in your `[]dataStruct` as the first argument you need to implement **all** those methods. The `InferID3Tree` relies on the **behaviour** (the methods) of that interface, if your type does not implement those methods and you try to pass it as the first argument your program will not even compile.

Comment: `/* ... */` is just a comment that you need to replace with real code. I'm not sure I understand what you mean in you second sentence of the comment, can you be more specific? Why do you actually need to convert your type into the `base.FixedDataGrid`? What does `CreateModel` do?

Comment: Actually here is what my function CreateModel doing: I taking data from mongodb to use it in machine learning training, my model is KNN.
And the `results` argument  in `base.InstancesTrainTestSplit()` has to be type `base.FixedDataGrid` ...

I Added the function createModel code in the question.

Comment: Thank you, it's clear. I'll try to implement this and come back to you if i need something. Thanks again

Comment: I have one more question: Should i let the `type dataStructList []dataStruct ` just like this? or should i add the other attributes like in `InstancesView` type like this:
`type InstancesView struct  {
        src                   FixesDataGrid
        attrs                []AttributeSpec
        rows                map[int]int
        classAttrs        map[attribute]bool
        maskRows      bool
}`

Because those attributes seems to be needed in the implementation of  `FixedDataGrid  ` functions...

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the `golearn` package so it's hard for me to tell, but to be able to pass your `type` to a function that takes an argument of type `FixesDataGrid` all you need to do is implement the methods of that interface and your program will compile. How you implement them is entirely up to you. So, if besides `[]dataStruct` you need to keep some extra *state* to make **your** implementation of those methods work the way **you** want, then yes, do wrap it in a `struct` with fields that will hold the relevant state, for example: https://play.golang.org/p/cYa8-f_Lq4